# Putty on client - error couldn't agree a key exchange algorithm

Tags: ssh, putty, sha1

My issue is that I have a putty client on a windows machine, trying to ssh to a Linux server (CentOS). The putty version is very old and it is NOT possible to take a newer version.

I would like to allow to use ***diffie-hellman-group1-sha1***, but the explanations I found here => https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/340844/how-to-enable-diffie-hellman-group1-sha1-key-exchange-on-debian-8-0 and here => http://www.openssh.com/legacy.html don't seem to be OK for my case. Because **in my case the client is old, not the server**. And this is putty on windows, not ssh from a Linux.

Do you have an idea how I could allow sha1 on my Linux server please ?

Thank you,

Comment: If you cannot change the client, you have to change the server. And that's what [the @arod's answer to the first question you have linked](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/340844/119732#370716) shows. But obviously using an old version of a security software is a bad idea.